# Code First TVF in 6.1.0-alpha1-30113

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

EF People,

My understanding is that the newly made public APIs for metadata will allow us to add enough metadata in to the model so that TVF can be called and be composable.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Without Composable TVF I have to jump through some major work a rounds.

From looking at the unit test it looks like something a long this line of thought:

```
var functionImport = EdmFunction.Create()
            "Foo", "Bar", DataSpace.CSpace,
            new EdmFunctionPayload
            {
                IsComposable = true,
                IsFunctionImport = true,
                ReturnParameters = new[]
                           {
                               FunctionParameter.Create("functionname", EdmType.GetBuiltInType()
                                   EdmConstants.ReturnType,
                                   TypeUsage.Create(collectionTypeMock.Object),
                                   ParameterMode.ReturnValue),
                           }
            });
...
entityContainer.AddFunctionImport(functionImport);
```

Thanks,
 Brian F

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is now possible in EF6.1. I actually created a custom model convention which allows using store functions in CodeFirst using the newly opened mapping API. The convention is available on NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions. Here is the link to the blogpost containing all the details: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/04/09/support-for-store-functions-tvfs-and-stored-procs-in-entity-framework-6-1/. The project is open source and you can get sources here: https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/